# I am trying to do simple hello world program using servlets. But i am getting an error HTTP status 405 - Method not allowed

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

When I run Servlet in the browser I am getting this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsnaT.png)

> HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
> Type Status Report
> Message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
> Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.54

HelloWorld.java File

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the `doPost()` method, but you are sending a GET request.
Change `doPost()` to `doGet()`